# CakePHP - Custom Route Controller

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3, url-routing

Is there anyway for me to create dynamic custom routes? The goal is to allow users to specify any URL they want to route to any controllers/view/ structure.

If user want to create something as below:

```
/a_quick_brown_fox => foxes/view/42
/jumps_over        => actions/view/42
/lazy_dog          => dogs/view/42
```

And many others in the future without the need to edit routes.php I am unsure of a possible solution.

I wish to allow user to input something like below

```
Custom URL  => [        ]
Controller  => [        ]
ID for View => [        ]
```

I will store it in a table to allow for unique URL checking, and what not. To allow scalability for new controllers I am okay with having prefix to slugs such as `/l/<slug>`

I would then wish to insert some code that will retrieve the custom URL from table and allow the routing. Is it at all possible? Has anyone ever done it?

Comment: So you want to have a form on a page that would redirect the user to the specified page? Or where would the user put the input?

Comment: I believe I didn't clarify what I would do with POST data. I made an edit right after the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have the routes controller do the saving of new routes and to cache saved routes. Each time a new route is added flush the cache and save it again.

Then create a custom Route class that will pull the cache entries out and process them in the routes.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you can define it directly into the routing system as you propose, however you could do something like this.

First define all your applications controller/actions explicitly so that your users won't overwrite them.

Then define a catch all route that will route to a controller of your choosing

```
//default routes
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
//other    

//custom route
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'routes', 'action' => 'custom'));
```

Your routes_controller/custom_action will receive whatever parameters the url contains, simply do a lookup on your DB from there and redirect to the correct route defined in your database.

```
function custom() {
    //get values via $this->params
}
```

Comment: I quite like the way it was going to the routes/custom/. But it still doesn't achieve the result of having a "pretty url" due to redirection.

Comment: ah yes, it won't retain the url it came in on. Have you had a look a this? : http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom route class, but I don't think you have access to POST data in it (you can access GET data and Cache, if that's enough). Probably the easiest way is redirect in the controller.

Comment: Please check out my edited question. I wish to store the POST data via a normal controller into a table. And create routing using the stored table data.